# Surds exam question rationalising

Tags: irrational-numbers, rationalising-denominator

This a surds question which is grade 8 according to the new GCSE'S which I have tried to work out but I keep getting the wrong answer.

Question: x is an integer such that:

${\frac{\sqrt {x} × \sqrt {18}}{\sqrt 3}}$ = ${8}{\sqrt 3}$

Find the value of x.

What I did:

${\frac{\sqrt {x} × \sqrt {18}}{\sqrt 3}}$ = ${8}{\sqrt 3}$    (×${\sqrt 3}$)

${\frac{\sqrt{54x}}{3}}$ = 24     (×3)

$\sqrt{54x}$ = 72  (×$\sqrt{}$)

54x = 5184  (÷54)

× = 96

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you and help is apprecaited

Comment: $\sqrt{54}\sqrt x = 72$ and so $\sqrt x=72/\sqrt{54}$.

Comment: Thankyou I understand now. ☺

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the first step onthe left hand side as you multiply by $\sqrt{3}$.

The left hand side should be $\sqrt{18x}$.

It should be $$\sqrt{18x}=24$$

Comment: Oh okay I understand when you times it by surd 3 you just get the surd 18x  Thankyou☺

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}=1\neq\frac{1}{3}$$

so the second step onwards is continued by

$$\sqrt{18x}=24$$
$$18x=24^2$$
$$x=\frac{24×24}{18}$$
$$x=32$$

Comment: Thankyou I had made a silly error causing the whole question to turn out wrong.☺